# Measure time in ONLY HOUR format

Tags: customization, formatting, timestamp

I need to change the timeformat in this column

[image]

to be in hours, not measured in seconds and minutes. This meaning that 30 minutes should be measured in 0.5 hours and so on.

I think I need to edit this line of code. Any suggestions on how to change the measurement to ONLY HOURS?

```
return human_time_diff(strtotime($item['time_login']), strtotime($item['time_last_seen']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE.

You can try to [filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3780) it with:

```
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'wpse_hourly_human_time_diff', 10, 4 );
```

where the filter's callback is e.g.

```
/**
 * Human time difference in hours only.
 *
 * @param string $since The difference in human readable text.
 * @param int    $diff  The difference in seconds.
 * @param int    $from  Unix timestamp from which the difference begins.
 * @param int    $to    Unix timestamp to end the time difference.
 */
function wpse_hourly_human_time_diff( $since, $diff, $from, $to ){
    return round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS, 1 );
}
```

but you will need to control where you want to apply this filter with:

```
remove_filter( 'human_time_diff', 'wpse_hourly_human_time_diff', 10 );
```

and further restrictions.

Hope you can adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The human_time_diff() function is not going to work without modification.

Here's a working solution using simple PHP:

```
$login = '2020-09-28 10:00:00';
$last_seen = '2020-09-28 09:30:00';

$diff = strtotime($login) - strtotime($last_seen);

$hours = $diff / ( 60 * 60 );

return $hours;
```